# Get last entered record for each item from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

how to join t_detail and t_header mysql, by group by item, by taking the last data record ?

```
id | doc | item | price
1  | 002 | asz  | 1200
2  | 002 | aqw  | 3000
3  | 002 | qwe  | 1300
4  | 005 | qwe  | 1000
5  | 005 | aqw  | 2000
```

output

```
id | doc | item | price
1  | 002 | asz  | 1200
4  | 005 | qwe  | 1000
5  | 005 | aqw  | 2000
```

Comment: What are you asking? Why did 2 and 3 get ignored from the output? What is `t_detail` and `t_header`?

Comment: There is only one table here

Comment: I believe @iswadi is asking for a query to display the last entered record for each item. (i.e. the last `asz`, the last `qwe` and the last `aqw`) ?

Comment: @Gnippots yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: expanding on @Kushan's answer

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table t2 
WHERE t2.item = t1.item GROUP BY item )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table GROUP BY item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use GROUP BY and JOIN :

SELECT id,doc,item,price  
FROM Table1
JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(Id) _Id,item
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY item    
) A ON A._Id = id
```

Answer (score 0):

for more performance :

```
SELECT 
    d.* 
FROM 
   t_detail d INNER JOIN 
            (
               SELECT 
                  MAX(id) as 'id' 
               FROM t_detail 
            GROUP BY item
            ) dmax on d.id = dmax.id ;
```

this way the query is executed only one time .